# Proof that counter mode of operation and CBC mode are CPA secure when pseudorandom permutations?

Tags: cbc

I know counter mode can be CPA secure, when used with block ciphers modeled as  random permutations. If we use pseudo-random permutations, is it still CPA secure? Is there a proof?

How about CBC mode? When used with block ciphers modeled as pseudo-random permutations, will it be CPA secure? Again, is there a proof?

Answer (score 3):

Standard security proofs for CTR and CBC deal with pseudo-random permutations (or pseudo-random functions). Relevant references can be found in Sections 4 and 5 of [Rogaway's survey](http://web.cs.ucdavis.edu/~rogaway/papers/modes.pdf). However, it is unclear what you mean by a proof with *random* permutations. Where is the key then?